# How to Append Dynamic Template in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I want to create a directive like:

```
<div ng-refreshing-when="x">Some Content In Here</div>
```

so when x=true, it will do some css and fade a spinner div over top, then when x=false, the spinner will fade out. I want to append a div (which is hidden by css) to the parent div, NOT replace the content. My current code is here, but the ngRefreshingWhen isn't triggering the ng-if:

http://plnkr.co/edit/griUYR6RY46x5DlqVHWU?p=preview

I set:

```
 $scope.refreshing = false;
```

so the "refreshing" text shouldn't be there...
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: different approach but would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20740213/creating-an-ajax-loading-spinner-using-a-directive-in-angularjs

Comment: just as a side note, it's not recommended to create custom directives which start with `ng-`, as `ng-` are meant to signify that the directive is implemented in the core framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        <div> <!-- Parent Div -->
          <div ng-refreshing-when="refreshing"></div>
          <p>Some Stuff I Want to Keep</p>
        </div>
```

&

```
angular.module('ngRefreshingWhen', [])
  .directive('ngRefreshingWhen', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        ngRefreshingWhen: '='
      },
      template: '<div class="refresher" ng-if="ngRefreshingWhen"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // add has-refresher class
        element.parent().addClass('has-refresher');
      }
    };
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xRgqqOfz9IuskL1kn057?p=preview

I did it differently, I added directive inside, then added the needed class to it's parent, same result, just added an element instead of trying to add an attribute to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `transclude` and put the HTML in the `template:`...

```
angular.module('ngRefreshingWhen',[])
    .directive('ngRefreshingWhen', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div class="refresher" ng-if="ngRefreshingWhen"><p>Refreshing</p></div><div ng-if="!ngRefreshingWhen" ng-transclude></div>',
            scope: {
                ngRefreshingWhen: '='
            }
        };
    });
```

If the HTML is more complicated, put it in a separate file and use `templateUrl`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/28Eq0HARKF0KXpYJwBTS?p=preview

Comment: I'm aware of using templates and trnasclusion, but the issue is I need to apply a class to the div, then _append_ the template code right after the '<p>Some Stuff</p>' that's inside the div with the directive.