# Modify or access angular interceptors after config phase

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angularjs-http, angular-http-interceptors, angularjs-injector

Is it possible to access / modify `$http` interceptors after the config phase? I'm debugging an app that only breaks in production due to being deployed on a different server, so unfortunately I can't change the interceptor code locally and figure out what's going on.

If it's not possible to access / modify the interceptors, perhaps it'd be possible to replace `$http`. Here's an example of replacing a hypothetical service:

```
var inj = angular.element('body').injector(),
    oldGet = inj.get,
    mockService = { secret: 'shhh' };

inj.get = function(str) {
  if (str === 'some-service') {
    return mockService;
  } else {
    return oldGet.apply(inj, arguments);
  }
};
```

However, I'm not sure how I'd go about creating a new `$http` service (into which I could pass in the modified interceptors). I can't grab the `$httpProvider`, either.

Perhaps bootstrapping a new `ng-app` on a separate part of the page would work? Then I could grab the `$http` service and replace it, like above.

Other ideas:

- With reference to: [Right way to disable/remove http interceptors in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293650/right-way-to-disable-remove-http-interceptors-in-angular) , it does not seem like I can access the interceptors array if I don't hold on to it in the config phase.
- Perhaps I can use grease monkey to inject something that runs in the config phase.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can add a new dummy interceptor to the interceptor pipeline just for your tracking purpose for now and later remove. This should be a pass through interceptor.

Comment: How would I do this after the config phase?

Comment: Yes you cannot do it at config stage, but what is the problem with config stage. Remember you can even write a dummy interceptor in a separate module and use the module's config stage to register the interceptor.

Comment: I was thinking that I'd have to use grease monkey to get that code in fast enough, which is fine (although I haven't tried, so maybe grease monkey will not work for that purpose), but I was wondering if there was another way to do it afterward.