# Angular httpinterceptor and timeout

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a page where lots of API calls is projected . I need to cancel all the API calls when I click a button.

I know that we can pass timeout and achieve this. But for this I need to add timeout attribute by assiging `$q.defer()` for all my api calls. So I thought of doing this using httpinterceptor area.

But I can't pass a `$q.defer()` to an interceptor from my controller. Since `$scope` is not accessible in the httpinterceptor.

Help me to share the `$q.defer()` between controller and httpinterceptor, so that I could reject the `$q.defer()` in the button's click event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303973/set-rootscope-variable-on-httpintercept This link may be help you :)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647483/angularjs-injecting-service-into-a-http-interceptor-circular-dependency

Comment: There were couple of typos and formatting issues